# What simple Scenario healthcheck message JSONdate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, endpoint, jackson-dataformat-xml, health-check

I have trouble in applying Java Spring boots with some rules:
 - If parameters values do not match the specifics possible values you should return HTTP status code 400("Bad Request")
 - Responses should have Content-Type header with approriate value(application/json)
 - If you need to create multiple classes
 - You can use only the following libraries:

- Spring web MVC (v.5.0.7.Release)
- Faster XML Jackson, Jackson datatype JSR310

I need detailed method read healtcheck with message:
{"currentTime" : "2020-06-01T20:45:35Z,"application":"OK"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customise the health check endpoint by implementing [HealthIndicator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthIndicator.html) and providing custom logic.

For example, you can check out simple implementation here (https://www.amitph.com/custom-health-check-spring-boot-actuator/).

Comment: I've tried, with a couple of scenarios. Could you please come in @Restcontroller

Comment: I've tried, with a couple of scenarios. Could you please come in @Restcontroller

class HealthcheckController
{@Getmapping(value = "/healthcheck", produces=MediaType.XML.Value)
Public Void() { return "healtcheck" + new date format(); }}

Comment: That's a different understanding of your question. If you want to create a controller with 'healthcheck' as a request URI, then probably yes. You need to create one wrapper for ({"currentTime" : "2020-06-01T20:45:35Z,"application":"OK"}) with simple class with containing fields as data member . You can feed the values and supply as a response.